# How to build Gnome Commander on 18.04 (Bionic)?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, package-management, programming

After successfully building Gnome commander for 19.04 (Disco Dingo) (you can download PPA here: https://launchpad.net/~schollsky/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-commander), I'm trying to do the trick with 18.04.

However, the package won't build and I have no clue where to search for the origin of the error, as the build log isn't informative enough for me.

Please share your thoughts on this one.

```
    ==========================================
 Ready to build GNOME Commander 1.10.2
==========================================

The following settings will be used:

  host             : x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  prefix           : /usr
  compiler         : gcc
  CXXFLAGS         : -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security
  LDFLAGS          : -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro

  libunique support:      no
  Samba support:          yes

Optional file metadata support:

  Exif support   : yes
  IPTC support   : yes
  ID3 support    : yes
  Vorbis support : yes
  APE support    : yes
  FLAC support   : yes
  OLE2 support   : yes
  ODF support    : yes
  PDF support    : yes

Type 'make' to build gnome-commander-1.10.2 and then 'make install' to install

   dh_auto_build
    make -j4
make[1]: Entering directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>'
make  all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>'
Making all in libgcmd
make[3]: Entering directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/libgcmd'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1   -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread   -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c -o gnome-cmd-plugin.lo gnome-cmd-plugin.cc
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1   -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread   -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c -o gnome-cmd-file-info.lo gnome-cmd-file-info.cc
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1   -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread   -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c -o gnome-cmd-dialog.lo gnome-cmd-dialog.cc
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2  -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1   -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread   -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c -o gnome-cmd-string-dialog.lo gnome-cmd-string-dialog.cc
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c gnome-cmd-file-info.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gnome-cmd-file-info.o
cc1plus: error: -Werror=cast-function-type: no option -Wcast-function-type
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c gnome-cmd-dialog.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gnome-cmd-dialog.o
Makefile:581: recipe for target 'gnome-cmd-file-info.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [gnome-cmd-file-info.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1plus: error: -Werror=cast-function-type: no option -Wcast-function-type
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
Makefile:581: recipe for target 'gnome-cmd-dialog.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [gnome-cmd-dialog.lo] Error 1
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c gnome-cmd-string-dialog.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gnome-cmd-string-dialog.o
cc1plus: error: -Werror=cast-function-type: no option -Wcast-function-type
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
Makefile:581: recipe for target 'gnome-cmd-string-dialog.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [gnome-cmd-string-dialog.lo] Error 1
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=gnu++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -pthread -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -pthread -DGTK_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -DGDK_PIXBUF_DISABLE_SINGLE_INCLUDES -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wextra -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wformat=2 -Wcast-align -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-aliasing -Wshadow -Winline -Wpacked -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wunused-but-set-variable -Warray-bounds -Wreturn-type -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wswitch-enum -Wswitch-default -Wno-error=unused-parameter -Wno-error=missing-field-initializers -Wno-error=overloaded-virtual -Werror=parentheses -Wno-parentheses -Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -c gnome-cmd-plugin.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/gnome-cmd-plugin.o
cc1plus: error: -Werror=cast-function-type: no option -Wcast-function-type
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’
Makefile:581: recipe for target 'gnome-cmd-plugin.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [gnome-cmd-plugin.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>/libgcmd'
Makefile:551: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>'
Makefile:481: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/<<PKGBUILDDIR>>'
dh_auto_build: make -j4 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:18: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Build finished at 20191229-0426

Finished
--------

E: Build failure (dpkg-buildpackage died)
```

Comment: Looks like you have to somehow remove `-Wcast-function-type` from the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

The `cast-function-type` flags are supported from GCC 8, but Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has GCC 7.4.0, so here they are not supported on launchpad.

You have to remove `-Werror=cast-function-type -Wno-cast-function-type` from all makefiles - `Makefile.in` and `Makefile.am` and then retry.

---

See also: https://gcmd.github.io/2019/05/30/gcmd-ubuntu-deb.html .

Comment: Is it not possible to tell launchpad to use GCC 8? I'd rather not fiddle with the source that much.

Comment: I have never done this on launchpad. Patching is trivial. You change build-options but not application functionality.